ESP32 receives a blank data (empty message) from Lora UART
I have successfully enabled Lora over ESP32 receiver and transmitter (with a lot of help here:)), however, I have struggling for hours in the receiver side, data received is empty - blank!
I have tried to debug all the code again and again and tried many ways of receiving messages, but all has returned empty message. I have searched in many forums, apparently its not common project.
if you guys can please help
I'm using ESP32-Wroom-32 and Lora E220-400T22S. coding in ESP-IDF while enabled Arduino in it.
transmitter code:
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "LoRa_E22.h"
#define ECHO_TEST_TXD (17)
#define ECHO_TEST_RXD (16)
//  esp32 RX <-- e220 TX, esp32 TX --> e220 RX AUX M0 M1
LoRa_E22 e220ttl(ECHO_TEST_TXD, ECHO_TEST_RXD, &Serial2, UART_BPS_RATE_115200); 

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    while(!Serial){};
    delay(500);
    Serial.println();


    // Startup all pins and UART
    e220ttl.begin();

    ResponseStructContainer c;
    c = e220ttl.getConfiguration();
    // It's important get configuration pointer before all other operation
    Configuration configuration = *(Configuration*) c.data;
    Serial.println(c.status.getResponseDescription());
    Serial.println(c.status.code);

    // printParameters(configuration);

//  ----------------------- DEFAULT TRANSPARENT -----------------------
    configuration.ADDL = 0x03;  // First part of address
    configuration.ADDH = 0x00; // Second part

    configuration.CHAN = 23; // Communication channel

    configuration.SPED.uartBaudRate = UART_BPS_RATE_115200; // Serial baud rate
    configuration.SPED.airDataRate = AIR_DATA_RATE_010_24; // Air baud rate
    configuration.SPED.uartParity = MODE_00_8N1; // Parity bit

    configuration.OPTION.subPacketSetting = SPS_240_00; // Packet size
    configuration.OPTION.RSSIAmbientNoise = RSSI_AMBIENT_NOISE_DISABLED; // Need to send special command
    configuration.OPTION.transmissionPower = POWER_22; // Device power

    configuration.TRANSMISSION_MODE.enableRSSI = RSSI_DISABLED; // Enable RSSI info
    configuration.TRANSMISSION_MODE.fixedTransmission = FT_FIXED_TRANSMISSION; // Enable repeater mode
    configuration.TRANSMISSION_MODE.enableLBT = LBT_DISABLED; // Check interference
    configuration.TRANSMISSION_MODE.WORPeriod = WOR_2000_011; // WOR timing


    // Set configuration changed and set to not hold the configuration
    ResponseStatus rs = e220ttl.setConfiguration(configuration, WRITE_CFG_PWR_DWN_SAVE);
    Serial.println(rs.getResponseDescription());
    Serial.println(rs.code);

    c = e220ttl.getConfiguration();
    // It's important get configuration pointer before all other operation
    configuration = *(Configuration*) c.data;
    Serial.println(c.status.getResponseDescription());
    Serial.println(c.status.code);

    // printParameters(configuration);
    c.close();
    // Startup all pins and UART
    e220ttl.begin();

    Serial.println("Hi, I'm going to send message!");

    // Send message
    e220ttl.sendBroadcastFixedMessage(23, "Hello, world?");
}


void loop() {
    
    Serial.println("Hi, I'm going to send message again!");
    ResponseStatus rs = e220ttl.sendBroadcastFixedMessage(23, "Hello, world?");
    // Check If there is some problem of succesfully send
    Serial.println(rs.getResponseDescription());
    delay(2000);
}

printout of this code:
Hi, I'm going to send message again!
sending message
Hello, world?
Success

receiver code:
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "LoRa_E22.h"
#define ECHO_TEST_TXD 17
#define ECHO_TEST_RXD 16

//  esp32 RX <-- e220 TX, esp32 TX --> e220 RX AUX M0 M1
LoRa_E22 e220ttl(ECHO_TEST_TXD, ECHO_TEST_RXD, &Serial2, UART_BPS_RATE_115200); 

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    while(!Serial){};
    delay(500);
    Serial.println();

    // Startup all pins and UART
    e220ttl.begin();

    ResponseStructContainer c;
    c = e220ttl.getConfiguration();
    // It's important get configuration pointer before all other operation
    Configuration configuration = *(Configuration*) c.data;
    Serial.println(c.status.getResponseDescription());
    Serial.println(c.status.code);

    // printParameters(configuration);

//  ----------------------- DEFAULT TRANSPARENT -----------------------
    configuration.ADDL = 0x04;  // First part of address
    configuration.ADDH = 0x00; // Second part

    configuration.CHAN = 23; // Communication channel

    configuration.SPED.uartBaudRate = UART_BPS_RATE_115200; // Serial baud rate
    configuration.SPED.airDataRate = AIR_DATA_RATE_010_24; // Air baud rate
    configuration.SPED.uartParity = MODE_00_8N1; // Parity bit

    configuration.OPTION.subPacketSetting = SPS_240_00; // Packet size
    configuration.OPTION.RSSIAmbientNoise = RSSI_AMBIENT_NOISE_DISABLED; // Need to send special command
    configuration.OPTION.transmissionPower = POWER_22; // Device power

    configuration.TRANSMISSION_MODE.enableRSSI = RSSI_DISABLED; // Enable RSSI info
    configuration.TRANSMISSION_MODE.fixedTransmission = FT_FIXED_TRANSMISSION; // Enable repeater mode
    configuration.TRANSMISSION_MODE.enableLBT = LBT_DISABLED; // Check interference
    configuration.TRANSMISSION_MODE.WORPeriod = WOR_2000_011; // WOR timing


    // Set configuration changed and set to not hold the configuration
    ResponseStatus rs = e220ttl.setConfiguration(configuration, WRITE_CFG_PWR_DWN_SAVE);
    Serial.println(rs.getResponseDescription());
    Serial.println(rs.code);

    c = e220ttl.getConfiguration();
    // It's important get configuration pointer before all other operation
    configuration = *(Configuration*) c.data;
    Serial.println(c.status.getResponseDescription());
    Serial.println(c.status.code);

    // printParameters(configuration);
    c.close();
    // Startup all pins and UART
    e220ttl.begin();

    Serial.println("Start receiving!");
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////

void loop() {
    // If something available
  if (e220ttl.available()>1) {
      Serial.println("Message received!");

      // read the String message

    ResponseContainer rc = e220ttl.receiveMessage();
    // Is something goes wrong print error
    if (rc.status.code!=1){
        Serial.println("here!");
        Serial.println(rc.status.getResponseDescription());
    }else{
        Serial.println("code is != 1 - received a message !");
        // Print the data received
        Serial.println(rc.status.getResponseDescription());
        Serial.println(rc.data);
        Serial.println(rc.data.length());
    }
  }
    delay(2000);
}

printout of this code:
the begining:
No response from device! (Check wiring)
12
++++++++++
Save mode returned not recognized!
11
Data size not match!
7

then, repeatedly,
Message received!
printing data from receive message complete

code is != 1 - received a message !
Success

3

where in above empty lines means empty message.
I have checked the wires again and again, and tried external supply or 5v supply from esp to the ebyte
Appreciate any help! Thanks in advance
